# Show first 10 letters from a string variable

Tags: php, string

I have a variable. I want to show 10 letter from there.

```
$msg = "Hello World! How are you.";
```

I want to show only `Hello Worl` this(first 10 letters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function

```
echo substr($msg, 0, 10);
```